# Error in SQL Connection String: Type is not defined

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I wrote this code:

```
 Public sqlConn As New SqlConnection
 Dim SQLConn As SqlConnection

'on form load
Sub FMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=...."
```

Upon executing it, I recieve this error:

> Error 1   Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.

What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Have you added a reference to system.data.dll and added the appropriate import statements?

Comment: Yes Alex  i added ..

Comment: If you had added the appropriate reference and import then it would be working, so I think it's safe to say that you haven't done both.

Comment: Actually, I've re-read your question and I wonder whether I misinterpreted it.  Is this a compilation error or a run-time exception?  If it's the latter, what is the actual type of the exception and where EXACTLY is it thrown?  If that's an error message coming from SQL Server then there may be something wrong with your SQL but you haven't shown us that.

Answer (score 0):

Your title says that there's an error in a connection string but that error has nothing to do with connection strings.  The `SqlConnection` class is a member of the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.  If you don't qualify the type name in code then you have to import the namespace.  As the `System.Data` namespace is imported by default, you can refer to it in code like this:

```
Public sqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
```

You can also import the namespace at the file level by adding this line at the top of the file:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

My preferred option for this namespace though, would be to import it at the project level.  That's because it's a namespace whose members you will tend to use in multiple files.  You can work with project-level imports on the bottom half of the References page in the project properties.